# Why bash think there is a syntax error on line 10?

Tags: bash

Shellcheck.net thinks this code is fine, but when I try to run it in bash, it returns a syntax error with unexpected operand on line 10 (".s")
What does that mean?

```
#! /bin/bash
date_on_file=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
ref_mnth=$(echo "$date_on_file"|awk '{print substr($1,5,2)}')
ref_day=$(echo "$date_on_file"|awk '{print substr($1,7,2)}')
for file in *
do
  mnth=$(echo "$file"|awk '{print substr($1,5,2)}')
  day=$(echo "$file"|awk '{print substr($1,7,2)}')
  if [[ $((mnth)) -lt $((ref_mnth)) ]] && [[ $((day)) -lt $((ref_day)) ]];then
    rm "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Expansions done at runtime cannot be caught with Shellcheck.  It means that the filenames picked-up with `*` are not in the format you expect them to be.  Run your script in debug mode which shows the expansions, for example:  `bash -x script-name`.  Your use of `$(( ))` inside `[[ ]]` is a very strange way to do it.

Comment: This test ```if [[ $((mnth)) -lt $((ref_mnth)) ]] && [[ $((day)) -lt $((ref_day)) ]];then``` can be simplified to ```if ((mnth < ref_mnth && day < ref_day)); then```.

Comment: You know Bash has built-in substring extraction like `mnth=${file:5:2}`?

Comment: Thank you very much for those tips, guys. I'm learning a lot from you!

Comment: Here is another tip: ```read -a date_on_file <<<$(date +"%Y %m %d %H %M")```. Using that you can refer to the month, for example, just using ```${date_on_file[1]}``` since the command creates an array with the output of the command.

Comment: @chepner, I already said that in my comment. :-)

Comment: Oops, only skimmed the first part :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize all the tips, here is an alternative version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -a ref_date <<< $(date +"%Y %m %d %H %M")
ref_month=${ref_date[1]}
ref_day=${ref_date[2]}
for file in *; do
    month=${file:5:2}
    day=${file:7:2}
    if ((month < ref_month && day < ref_day)); then
        rm "$file"
    fi
done
```

There is another way to get the fields on `ref_date` using bash regular expressions and the match operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M') =~ ^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..) ]]
ref_month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
ref_day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
for file in *; do
    if [[ $file =~ ^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..) ]]; then
        month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        if ((month < ref_month && day < ref_day)); then
            rm "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

The regular expressions are not optimized on purpose just to make it clear on what I'm matching and grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script with bash -x

```
bash -x yourscript.sh
```

You'll probably find that it stops on strings with special characters like dot or comma.

Your script is a bit chaotic, it's hard to tell what it actualy does, but before doing

```
if [[ $((mnth)) -lt $((ref_mnth)) ]] && [[ $((day)) -lt $((ref_day)) ]];then
```

you should first validate that variables has integer values to compare, as -lt only works for numeric vaules.

you might want to add something to debug this, like:

```
(...)
  echo "[debug] $((mnth)) $((ref_mnth)) $((day)) $((ref_day))"

  if [[ $((mnth)) -lt $((ref_mnth)) ]] && [[ $((day)) -lt $((ref_day)) ]];then
(...)
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're using double parentheses for your variables, cause they're used for arithmetic operations and you seem not to do such operations on them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another factor to worry about: August and September, when the month is "08" and "09"

```
$ mnth=04
$ ref_mnth=08

$ if ((mnth < ref_mnth)); then echo ok; fi
bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
$ if [[ $mnth -lt $ref_mnth ]]; then echo ok; fi
bash: [[: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

You either have to do some string manipulation to remove the leading zero, or explicitly tell bash that these are base-10 numbers, not octal

```
$ if ((10#$mnth < 10#$ref_mnth)); then echo ok; fi
ok
$ if [[ 10#$mnth -lt 10#$ref_mnth ]]; then echo ok; fi
ok
```

Comment: Good catch. That passed unnoticed by me.